# Vue: Using Vuex store in beforeRouteEnter hook to cancel navigation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I am trying to get vue-router to check a list of permissions, before finishing the navigation to a new route. The permissions are stored in vuex and ideally I'd want to avoid passing them as props everywhere.

When I use the `next(vm => {})` callback, regardless of the outcome, it routes to next page, even though it should receive `false` and cancel the navigation.

```js
beforeRouteEnter(to, undefined, next) {
  next(vm => {
    const allowedRoles = ['Administrator', 'Contributor'];
    if (vm.$store.state.authentication.userInfo.userRoles.some(value => allowedRoles.includes(value))) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here that is causing it to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you've accessed `vm` inside `next`, the navigation has already occurred.  Test the value before calling `next`.  You can import the store into the component to access it:

```js
import store from '@/store/index.js';  // import the store
```

```js
beforeRouteEnter(to, undefined, next) {
  const allowedRoles = ['Administrator', 'Contributor'];
  const roles = store.state.authentication.userInfo.userRoles;
  const isAllowed = roles.some(value => allowedRoles.includes(value))
  next(isAllowed);  // passes `true` or `false` to `next`
},
```

This way you can access the store without needing the component instance.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't use bundlers like webpack, instead we do things through a CDN like approach. If we tried to access Vuex outside of vue, we would have to manually sift out way through the browsers record of the Vuex instance. I take it a module bundler is the only real way round this?

Comment: The store is so integral to the app that it should be paramount to make it accessible from anywhere (even when using CDN).  I would add it to the `window` object if necessary.  There are other possibilities.  Can you access the store in the router?

Comment: Yep assigning to window got it. Although we avoid directly writting to window, so we put it in a nested class, e.g. Page.Vuex = new Vuex.Store({});
This meant we then could reference in router via Page.Vuex.state...